# We need to add a consent form to the API M portal

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management

We need to add a consent form to the API M portal, using the standard template.

Comment: What do you mean by API `M` portal? And  what should consent be given for?

Answer (score 0):

BY APIM I mean Azure API Management, we need to customize the standard build-in template to add a consent form to the signup form, so that we have consent from the users that they can access the required data pulled from the backend API.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/#features